# Error Ubuntu 22.00

Tags: 22.04

Good night, I forgot my user's password and I did it through the recovery of Ubuntu 22.04 itself, when I finish changing the password, restart and on the user screen to enter the changed password it says it is incorrect, can anyone help me?  my Ubuntu and version 22.04 LTS

Comment: Change the password again and be more careful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)